# How to get not empty row count?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I find myself doing a lot of operations on tables where I am not sure about entry count.

I simply guess that it should be lower than 100 and just do `=SUM(A1:A100)`. Now if I have only 2 entries, all the other rows are useless for other things.

How can I solve this problem? Maybe I can automatically detect continuous values without an empty row in between or something?

**I am not about performance.** If I use 100 rows for some formula just to be safe in the future but only 3 rows have values present I just wasted a lot of spreadsheet space making it harder to use and read.

**EDIT**

To explain what I mean by saying 'waste of space'. [image: spreadsheet]

I don't know how many name:value pairs I will have. Maybe 5 maybe 100. So in this case I have 3 entered but 5 empty columns. That means I have wasted 2 columns of space. When I want to be sure my calculations will handle a lot of values, I just do like `=SUM(A2:A100)` and leave it like that but then it's impossible to place `another attributes` or `more values`.

Comment: If there're less than 100 values, there shouldn't be any problem. I think that adding more functions would instead slow down the calculations.

Comment: I am not about performance but about the usability. If I count columns 1-100 but have only 3 values present I just waste a lot of spreadsheet space

Comment: Okay, I'm not so sure what you're trying to do still. It would be even harder to use if you use a lot of formulas that others might not understand. And I don't understand your concept of wasting space either. Any formula you use will have to check the whole range `A1:A100` from your example anyway.

Comment: For example I want to have a sum of all the expenses I have done. There may be 5 expenses or 50. I don't know so I just do =SUM(X1:X100) and be safe about it. But the problem now is that the whole column is wasted if there are for example only 5 numbers. Also it is useless if there are 200 entries. I want somehow to have flexible boundaries

Comment: Okay, there is something you might use: `=SUM(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(9^99,A:A)))` which will take whatever values until the last value in the column regardless of whether there are any blanks scattered inside the column, but as I said, it's unavoidable to check the whole column. I'd personally advise using simply `=SUM(A:A)`.

Comment: @Jerry thanks a lot. I will give it a try! By writing A:A you mean A1:Z1 or writing X:X works too? By the way, please post it as an answer

Comment: I meant to write `A:A`. Using this means it's checking the whole column regardless of how many rows there are. If you want to check the whole of column A, then use `A:A`.

Comment: Can you use a table? If you use a table you can refer to a specific column of the table and that will expand automatically when you add data - `Select your data > Insert > Table`

Comment: @barryhoudini I will try that. Seems to be what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use =CAUNTA() function.

[COUNTA](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/1tDRblSzPmQ)

Comment: this will only give a count of the number of non-blank cells, not a location of the last cell in the first data area.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not convinced how one could 'waste spreadsheet space' and I would recommend using simply `=SUM(A:A)` in such a case.

If you must sum up to the very last cell in column A, then maybe this formula would suit you:

```
=SUM(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(9^99,A:A)))
```

This formula will ignore any blanks if any and count down to the last value.

Another possible (and maybe simpler) formula is with `SUMIF`:

```
=SUMIF(A:A, "<>0")
```

Since blanks are considered as 0, they won't get summed, but as I said, I find it much simpler to just use `SUM(A:A)` since blanks are zeros anyway.

Comment: @lukas.pukenis Well, that changes everything! And I think you mean 'row' instead of 'column' because columns are vertical and rows are horizontal. In that case, I would ask something else: Are you having a sum for each (are they unique?) attribute?

Comment: I am sure I want to sum columns(vertical) but don't know how many entries there will be and would like to fill in the space with other textual information :)